# Подключение к MSSQL из Task

Tags: c#, sql-server

Добрый день.

Есть метод, который цепляется к базе и запускает хранимую процедуру. Выполнить нужно очень быстро и несколько раз подряд. Было решено запускать метод в 5-6 `Task` одновременно. При переводе на `Task` появилась проблема в соединении с MSSQL, а именно: 
`The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication`. Что так же примечательно, так это то, что последняя `Task` выполняется успешно

При этом, если выполнение 5-6 раз проходит в цикле, то ошибка не возникает.

В чём может быть проблема?

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
     using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
     {
          cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          cmd.CommandText = "thenameofstoredprocedure";
          conn.Open();
          cmd.Connection = conn;
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
 }
```

Comment: Покажите код. Наверное, ваш SQL-клиент не поддерживает многопоточнось/одновременные соединения?

Comment: Для многопоточной работы надо использовать какой-нибудь connection-pool. Возможно в этом проблема.

Comment: @VladD, указал в вопросе

Comment: Вы логинитесь к серверу под Windows Autentification?